# Count Unity terrain size In blender?

Tags: unity, blender, terrain

My unity terrain size is 150*150, and I want to create a plane in blender have the same size. How to figure the correct size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to answer in Unity forums [(link)](https://forum.unity.com/threads/blender-units-metres-and-measurements.133765/#post-906572):

> ...
>
> it's best to have 1 Blender Unit = 1 Unity Unit = 1 meter.
>
> If you create your Blender model, and it's scaled 1:1:1, and on import it's very teeny tiny...
>
> Check your import settings for that model.
>
> If you are using a targeted save pipeline and are saving the .blend file directly to your Assets Directory of your project, the import settings should be set to 1.
>
> If you are using an export import pipeline and are exporting to .fbx and importing the .fbx file into Unity, you may find that the import settings default to 0.01.
>
> I believe this is because Maya (and perhaps other) packages that save to .fbx use centimeters by default for scale, rather then meters.

Comment: Thank you man. if Unity terrain is 150*150 then blender panel should be 75*75 when export it as .fbx.